# Muchos errores al pasar mi código HTML de Stripo a Apps Script de google

Tags: javascript, html

actualmente estoy intentando crear correos automáticos para la empresa que trabajo y la plantilla HTML con el diseño la saque de stripo; los errores son de sintaxis y el error principal se manifiesta en la linea 13 --

var mensajeHTML = '

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego pegue el código en la consola de App Script el cual es una aplicación de Google para generar correos automáticos desde Google Sheets. Programe el código en Java script y añadí la variable para que lea la plantilla HTML pero no entiendo por que a pesar de haber revisado todo el código no logro encontrar las fallas. Son unas cuantas líneas las cuales tienen fallas. Quizá una persona con mayor conocimiento HTML me pueda ayudar.

Adjunto codigo

```html
function enviarEmailCumple() {

  const libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const hoja = libro.getActiveSheet();

  for (var fila = 1; fila <= hoja.getLastRow(); fila++) {
    const email = hoja.getRange(fila,10).getValue()
    const asunto = "Feliz Cumpleaños te desea Alquería "
    const nombre = hoja.getRange(fila,3).getValue()
    const mensaje = "Metodo de prueba"
    const status = hoja.getRange(fila,9).getValue()
    const estadoMail = hoja.getRange(fila,11).getValue()
    var mensajeHTML = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" style="width:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:0;Margin:0"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"><meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"><title>PLANTILLA CORREO </title><!--[if (mso 16)]><style type="text/css"> a {text-decoration: none;} </style><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><style>sup { font-size: 100% !important; }</style><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> <o:OfficeDocumentSettings> <o:AllowPNG></o:AllowPNG> <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch> </o:OfficeDocumentSettings> </xml><![endif]--><!--[if !mso]><!-- --><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet"><!--<![endif]--><style type="text/css">#outlook a { padding:0;}.ExternalClass { width:100%;}.ExternalClass,.ExternalClass p,.ExternalClass span,.ExternalClass font,.ExternalClass td,.ExternalClass div { line-height:100%;}.es-button { mso-style-priority:100!important; text-decoration:none!important;}a[x-apple-data-detectors] { color:inherit!important; text-decoration:none!important; font-size:inherit!important; font-family:inherit!important; font-weight:inherit!important; line-height:inherit!important;}.es-desk-hidden { display:none; float:left; overflow:hidden; width:0; max-height:0; line-height:0; mso-hide:all;}[data-ogsb] .es-button { border-width:0!important; padding:10px 20px 10px 20px!important;}@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {p, ul li, ol li, a { line-height:150%!important } h1, h2, h3, h1 a, h2 a, h3 a { line-height:120%!important } h1 { font-size:30px!important; text-align:center } h2 { font-size:26px!important; text-align:center } h3 { font-size:20px!important; text-align:center } .es-header-body h1 a, .es-content-body h1 a, .es-footer-body h1 a { font-size:30px!important } .es-header-body h2 a, .es-content-body h2 a, .es-footer-body h2 a { font-size:26px!important } .es-header-body h3 a, .es-content-body h3 a, .es-footer-body h3 a { font-size:20px!important } .es-menu td a { font-size:16px!important } .es-header-body p, .es-header-body ul li, .es-header-body ol li, .es-header-body a { font-size:16px!important } .es-content-body p, .es-content-body ul li, .es-content-body ol li, .es-content-body a { font-size:16px!important } .es-footer-body p, .es-footer-body ul li, .es-footer-body ol li, .es-footer-body a { font-size:16px!important } .es-infoblock p, .es-infoblock ul li, .es-infoblock ol li, .es-infoblock a { font-size:12px!important } *[class="gmail-fix"] { display:none!important } .es-m-txt-c, .es-m-txt-c h1, .es-m-txt-c h2, .es-m-txt-c h3 { text-align:center!important } .es-m-txt-r, .es-m-txt-r h1, .es-m-txt-r h2, .es-m-txt-r h3 { text-align:right!important } .es-m-txt-l, .es-m-txt-l h1, .es-m-txt-l h2, .es-m-txt-l h3 { text-align:left!important } .es-m-txt-r img, .es-m-txt-c img, .es-m-txt-l img { display:inline!important } .es-button-border { display:block!important } a.es-button, button.es-button { font-size:20px!important; display:block!important; border-width:10px 0px 10px 0px!important } .es-btn-fw { border-width:10px 0px!important; text-align:center!important } .es-adaptive table, .es-btn-fw, .es-btn-fw-brdr, .es-left, .es-right { width:100%!important } .es-content table, .es-header table, .es-footer table, .es-content, .es-footer, .es-header { width:100%!important; max-width:600px!important } .es-adapt-td { display:block!important; width:100%!important } .adapt-img { width:100%!important; height:auto!important } .es-m-p0 { padding:0px!important } .es-m-p0r { padding-right:0px!important } .es-m-p0l { padding-left:0px!important } .es-m-p0t { padding-top:0px!important } .es-m-p0b { padding-bottom:0!important } .es-m-p20b { padding-bottom:20px!important } .es-mobile-hidden, .es-hidden { display:none!important } tr.es-desk-hidden, td.es-desk-hidden, table.es-desk-hidden { width:auto!important; overflow:visible!important; float:none!important; max-height:inherit!important; line-height:inherit!important } tr.es-desk-hidden { display:table-row!important } table.es-desk-hidden { display:table!important } td.es-desk-menu-hidden { display:table-cell!important } .es-menu td { width:1%!important } table.es-table-not-adapt, .esd-block-html table { width:auto!important } table.es-social { display:inline-block!important } table.es-social td { display:inline-block!important } .es-desk-hidden { display:table-row!important; width:auto!important; overflow:visible!important; max-height:inherit!important } }</style></head>'+
<body style="width:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;padding:0;Margin:0"><div class="es-wrapper-color" style="background-color:#F6F6F6"><!--[if gte mso 9]><v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t"> <v:fill type="tile" color="#f6f6f6"></v:fill> </v:background><![endif]--><table class="es-wrapper" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;padding:0;Margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center top"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td valign="top" style="padding:0;Margin:0"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="es-content" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0"><table class="es-content-body" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:transparent;width:600px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" data-darkreader-inline-bgcolor><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px"><!--[if mso]><table style="width:560px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="width:270px" valign="top"><![endif]--><table class="es-left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:left"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:270px"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td class="es-infoblock" align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;line-height:14px;font-size:12px;color:#CCCCCC"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:14px;color:#CCCCCC;font-size:12px">Feiz Cumpleaños<br></p>
'</td></tr></table></td></tr></table><!--[if mso]></td><td style="width:20px"></td>'+
'<td style="width:270px" valign="top"><![endif]--><table class="es-right" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;float:right"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:270px"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="right" class="es-infoblock" style="padding:0;Margin:0;line-height:14px;font-size:12px;color:#CCCCCC"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:14px;color:#CCCCCC;font-size:12px"><a href="https://viewstripo.email" class="view" target="_blank" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;text-decoration:underline;color:#CCCCCC;font-size:12px">View in browser</a></p>'+
'</td></tr></table></td></tr></table><!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td></tr></table></td>'+
'</tr></table><table class="es-content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0"><table class="es-content-body" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#ffffff;width:600px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" data-darkreader-inline-bgcolor><tr class="es-visible-simple-html-only" style="border-collapse:collapse"><td class="es-struct-html" align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:35px;padding-left:40px;padding-right:40px"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:520px"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0"><h1 style="Margin:0;line-height:48px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:lora, georgia, 'times new roman', serif;font-size:40px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;color:#666666" data-darkreader-inline-color><em>¡Feliz Cumpleaños!</em></h1>'+
'+</td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:600px"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;font-size:0"><img class="adapt-img" src="https://vlxdgs.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_b54797fc68edcecf4f6b2835e7bcba32/images/36321522405737710.gif" style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic" alt="Gift " title="Gift " width="300"></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td>'+
'</tr><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:40px;padding-left:40px;padding-right:40px"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:520px"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#999999;font-size:14px" data-darkreader-inline-color>Para la familia Alqueria es un placer&nbsp;brindarte un acogedor feliz cumpleaños</p>'+
'<p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#999999;font-size:14px" data-darkreader-inline-color>esperamos poder acompañarte en muchos mas proceso como este</p></td></tr><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:15px"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:21px;color:#999999;font-size:14px" data-darkreader-inline-color><em>Mayores exitos, Familia Alqueria.&nbsp;</em></p></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td>'+
'</tr></table><table class="es-content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0"><table class="es-content-body" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#c4dbf2;width:600px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#c4dbf2" align="center" data-darkreader-inline-bgcolor><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:30px"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:560px"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;font-size:0px"><img class="adapt-img" src="https://vlxdgs.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_6688da0e34898e7e8d30cbb12758182e/images/logo_silueta.png" alt style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic" width="560"></td>'+
'</tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td>'+
'</tr></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="es-footer" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%;background-color:transparent;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center top"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0"><table class="es-footer-body" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:#ffffff;width:600px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" data-darkreader-inline-bgcolor><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="left" style="padding:0;Margin:0"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:600px"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td esdev-links-color="#666666" align="center" class="es-m-txt-с" style="padding:0;Margin:0;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:20px"><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:18px;color:#666666;font-size:12px" data-darkreader-inline-color>Copyright © 2018 Run, All rights reserved.</p>'+
'<p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:18px;color:#666666;font-size:12px" data-darkreader-inline-color>You are receiving this email because you have visited our site or asked us about regular newsletter.</p><p style="Margin:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-family:arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:18px;color:#666666;font-size:12px" data-darkreader-inline-color><a target="_blank" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;text-decoration:underline;color:#666666;font-size:12px;line-height:18px" class="unsubscribe" href="" data-darkreader-inline-color>Unsubscribe</a></p></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td>'+
'</tr></table><table class="es-content" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;table-layout:fixed !important;width:100%"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0"><table class="es-content-body" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;background-color:transparent;width:600px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" data-darkreader-inline-bgcolor><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td align="left" style="Margin:0;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:30px"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td valign="top" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;width:560px"><table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px"><tr style="border-collapse:collapse"><td class="es-infoblock made_with" align="center" style="padding:0;Margin:0;line-height:120%;font-size:0;color:#CCCCCC"><a target="_blank" href="https://viewstripo.email/?utm_source=templates&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=software&utm_content=birthday" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;text-decoration:underline;color:#CCCCCC;font-size:12px"><img src="https://vlxdgs.stripocdn.email/content/guids/CABINET_9df86e5b6c53dd0319931e2447ed854b/images/64951510234941531.png" alt width="125" style="display:block;border:0;outline:none;text-decoration:none;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic"></a></td>'+
'</tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div></body></html>';
    
    if (status == "HOY ES SU CUMPLEAÑOS" && estadoMail !="ENVIADO") {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(email,asunto + nombre,'',{htmlBody:mensajeHTML});
      hoja.getRange(fila,11).setValue("ENVIADO")

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Mencionás que hay fallas pero no mencionás cuáles. Pulsá en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. Leé [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Como detalle adicional, cuidá la redacción del mensaje a enviar: los errores de tipeo/ortográficos dan una mala imagen a la empresa.